# Triggering a file when a file is uploaded in a ftp

Tags: ftp, ftplib, ftp-server

i am just wondering is there any such feature available!

When user uploads file to a FTP once the connection is disconnected, FTP server need to trigger a event to start a program, so the program can work on the uploaded files.

Am i asking a features which is already available ?

Answer (score 0):

The FTP program itself cannot execute a application, though you could try checking if the file is infact uploaded and then use PHP to execute the file you want.

I used it once for uploading and compiling a c# program.

Hope this helps, else further explain please.